Changes to strapi files are not reflected on the admin page
I'm using Strapi API and trying to set up the email part.
I made the changes in config/plugins.js, but they are not reflected in the admin page.
I gave the commands npm run build and npm run develop -- --debug.
What do I do? I've tried to run it even through docker, but without success, the changes don't reflect on the page.
I ran the commands npm run build and npm run develop -- --debug.
In addition, I've tried to run it even through docker, but without success.
console.log('Carregando variáveis de ambiente...');
console.log('SMTP_PROVIDER:', process.env.SMTP_PROVIDER);
console.log('MAIL_DEFAULT_REPLY_TO:', process.env.MAIL_DEFAULT_REPLY_TO);
console.log('MAIL_TEST_DEFAULT:', process.env.MAIL_TEST_DEFAULT);

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  return {
    email: {
      config: {
        provider: env('SMTP_PROVIDER'),
        providerOptions: {
          host: env('SMTP_HOST'),
          port: env.int('SMTP_PORT'),
          secure: env.bool('SMTP_SECURE'),
          auth: {
            user: env('SMTP_USERNAME'),
            pass: env('SMTP_PASSWORD'),
          },
        },
        settings: {
          defaultFrom: env('MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM'),
          defaultReplyTo: env('MAIL_DEFAULT_REPLY_TO'),
          testAddress: env('MAIL_TEST_DEFAULT'),
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

